# How to change the values of specific nested array in json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have the below .json file and I just want to change the down and up values based on user input.

```
"android": {
    "appium:autoAcceptAlerts": true,
    "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
    "appium:newCommandTimeout": 180,
    "appium:appPackage": "com.android.settings",
    "appium:platformName": "android",
    "appium:capture.networkConfig": {
      "shaping": {
          "down":5,
          "up": 2
      }
      }
},
```

The above json body I'm trying to change the "down" attribute from "5" to "2" and "up" attribute from "2" to "1" by using the below code.

```
 if(state == 'high')
    {
        let tempVal = caps[platform];  // let platform = 'android'
        console.log("**********************");
        console.log(tempVal);  // It's printing the json body.
    
        for(let prep in tempVal)
        {
          tempVal[prep].shaping.down = 2;   //Not replaced.
          tempVa[prep].shaping.up = 1;    //Not replaced.

          console.log(tempVal[prep].shaping.down); // It's not printing down and returned as undefined.
        }
        console.log("**********************")
    }
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, is caps still JSON or is it parsed ?

Comment: It's parsed and I can able to print until temp[prep].shaping and it's giving output of {down:5, up:2}. But I'm not able to further go and change the down and Up values.

Comment: caps.platform.android['appium:capture.networkConfig'].shaping.down = 2;
caps.platform.android['appium:capture.networkConfig'].shaping.up = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if(state == 'high')
{
    let tempVal = caps[platform];  // let platform = 'android'
    console.log("**********************");
    console.log(tempVal);  // It's printing the json body.
let prep = 'appium:capture.networkConfig';
   
      tempVal[prep].shaping.down = 2;   
      tempVa[prep].shaping.up = 1;    

      console.log(tempVal[prep].shaping.down);  
    
    console.log("**********************")
}
```